# Silverlight change color custom control programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have this Ellipse which I turned into a custom control so I could animate it programmatically. However I am having trouble changing its color.

I know about changing a shapes color like this:

```
aRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

However I cannot do this with a custom control.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

How you set the color would depend on the template for the control, but in general I believe there is a Foreground brush property on the Control class. You should probably have all of the parts of your template honor this property so the entire control is colored properly.